# Aloe plant has come out of the dirt what can I go with the aloe and how long can it last

Tags: aloe

My plant came out of the dirt I believe it got too leggy how can I salvage the plant outside of the dirt and
how long can it last without dirt

Comment: A desert plant can go a month without soil or water, but why not pot it soon? Break it in half, harvest the juice, let it dry a day or two, and then pot up both parts separately.